# Where does "shakedown" come from?

Tags: etymology

I am referring  to ***[shakedown](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shakedown)*** meaning ***a thorough search*** as in :

> - *the morning after their arrival, scouts and their leaders endure the shakedown, where their backpacks are inspected with drill sergeant thoroughness*. (ODO)
> - *a shakedown of prison cells to uncover hidden drugs*
> - *tighter security measures and shakedowns at airports have increased dramatically in recent years.*

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=Shakedown)  says that the meaning "a thorough search"   ***is from 1914; perhaps from the notion of measuring corn.***

I couldn't find other evidence on its etymology;

- what does "*measuring corn*" refer to?
- how is this practice related to a "*thorough search*"?
- are there other plausible assumptions on its origin?

Comment: I've always envisioned it as picking up the poor victim of the shakedown, turning him upside-down, and shaking vigorously, to see what falls out.  (More consistent with the "extortion" meaning, which is what I think of first.)

Comment: (I am certainly doubtful of the "measuring corn" etymology for the gangster sense of the term.  And note that [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shakedown) defines the term as "Another word for extortion/blackmail, or the obtaining of a good or service through means of force, threats/intimidation, or abuse of power.")

Comment: Josh, you need to give us an example of the usage in the sense you mean.  The expression has about four different meanings.

Comment: @HotLicks - the meaning I am referring to is "thorough search* as stated in my question.

Comment: I don't think asking for an example sentence is too much to ask for, especially as the site has so many non-native speakers who will probably unfamiliar with the expression. See also the answer you received... You could make it clearer that you don't see the connection between *shake up/down* with corn.

Comment: Does one have to  *shake* the kernels of corn? Is *shake* a deviation of *shuck*? http://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-husk-corn-quickly-cleanly-cooking-lessons-from-the-kitchn-192664

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I thought about corn in the sense of "setacciare", but they say "measuring". Probably measuring corn refers  to "sift".

Comment: Josh, there are several different ways that "thorough search" could be applied.  An actual example is needed.

Comment: @HotLicks - I've added 2 examples.

Comment: You have two different contexts, likely with different derivations.  The first mixes of the connotation of "shakedown cruise" with the "search" connotation.  The second is a pure search, and is likely derived from the "turn him over and shake" origin.  The "shakedown cruise" meaning is likely based on the idiom of shaking a machine to see what loose parts fall out.

Comment: And the "shakedowns at airports" sense nicely fits the "turn him over and shake" metaphor.

Comment: @HotLicks - you rightly insist on an intuitive explanation, but the question is on the "***measuring corn"*** issue. Etymonline does not mention the "turn over and shake" intuitive origin.

Comment: To further confuse things I'll toss in another possible source of the term.  Consider a fruit tree.  You may shake it to "shake down" some fruit.  Shakespeare apparently used "shake down" in this sense.

Comment: @HotLicks - interesting but pure speculations, we need hard evidence here at ELU :)

Comment: Re "measuring corn", I have no idea how that might provide a source.  Perhaps the grain is placed in a bucket and shook to settle the kernels before measuring height, or perhaps the grain is "shook" in the process of threshing.  Or perhaps there is no relationship at all.  (Wouldn't be the first time.)

Comment: @HotLicks - that is the point. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @Mari-Lau A - you mean It is a good question? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*OED* says that the noun *shake-down* is from the verbal phrase *to shake down* and links to this definition of the verb *shake* (sense 12a):

> With adv. or phrase: To reduce by shaking (sense [7](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/177308#eid23129224)) to a specified condition. **to shake down:** to cause to settle or subside by shaking.

There is also an obsolete definition of the verb *shake* related to corn and it links to sense 12a:

> *simply.* To cast down, scatter (fruit, blossom, corn, etc.) by shaking; = [*to shake down* at sense 12a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granular_convection)   above. Also, to turn out (a fox) from a bag (cf. [*to shake out* 1 at Phrasal verbs][2]).

The earliest citation is from 1557 and includes a proverbial phrase:

> All this wynde shoke no corne, all this moued him not.
>
> <sub>R. Edgeworth *Serm. very Fruitfull* ccxxx. C 1</sub>

And a non-obsolete and dialectal definition:

> *intr.* Of fruit, blossom, corn: To fall, scatter. Now *dial.*

Here is a 1788 citation from the book *The rural economy of Yorkshire* (by William Marshall) where the verb *shake* is mentioned in the provincialism of East York:

> To *Shack* (that is, to *shake*), to shed, as corn at harvest.

I've checked Google Books also and found this excerpt in the *Report from the Select Committee on the Sale of Corn: With the Minutes of Evidence, Appendix and Index* (ordered, by The House of Commons, to be printed, 25 July 1834):

> In measuring corn in England, the system is to measure lightly as it is termed, by pouring it gently into the bushel measure, or by entering the measure itself into a loose heap of corn so as partially to fill it, and then completing the filling of it by the hands ; and afterwards by passing the strike, or wooden ruler, along the top of the measure, when a little more than full, in order to scrape off the superfluous parts. By our ancient laws, it was illegal not only to require more than eight bushels to the quarter of corn, which appears to have been a common practice, but even **to shake the bushel in measuring corn, which process compresses it into a smaller space, and therefore requires a greater quantity to fill the same measure.** These statutes were enacted in the feudal ages, when rents were paid partly in kind, to protect the vassals, who were obliged to deliver a certain number of bushels of corn to their lords at stated times, from being harshly dealt with, by having compressed instead of loose measure exacted from them.

As a side note, *bushel* is a measure of capacity used for corn, fruit, etc., containing four pecks or eight gallons. The ***imperial bushel***, legally established in Great Britain in 1826, contains 2218.192 cubic inches, or 80 pounds of distilled water weighed in air at 62° Fah. The ***Winchester bushel***, much used from the time of Henry VIII, was somewhat smaller, containing 2150.42 cubic inches or 77.627413 pounds of distilled water; it is still generally used in United States and Canada.<sup>[*OED*]</sup>

---

**Conclusion:**

The noun *shake-down* meaning "a thorough search of a person or place" seems like an analogy to the act of shaking the corn down till it settles and there is no space left to fill in order to get a good measure. So in criminal slang, it is searching someone or somewhere till there is nothing left to search.

Note: In physics, the shakedown mechanism is explained with *[granular convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granular_convection)*.

Comment: I'd just like to reiterate my congratulations on answering this difficult question. A really good answer, which deserved more recognition.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has got something to do with unloading things from a container, making sure nothing is left.

Comment: How would one get "extortion" from that?

Comment: from the OP: *"I am referring to shakedown meaning a thorough search."*

Comment: By the way I am not a native speaker of English and  I just made a guess.

Comment: But "thorough search" is, I'm pretty sure, in a different sense from what you think.  I would take it to mean "search the victim thoroughly for valuables or a specific item that is wanted from him".

Comment: Longman Dictionary: *"a thorough search of a place or a person: No weapons were found during the shakedown."*

Comment: I'd still go with turning over and shaking.

Comment: This does not answer any of the three questions asked by the OP.